# getting text off webpage (NOT HTML SOURCE)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

how would i put the contents of a webpage into a string?

it would be the same thing as hitting ctrl+A and copying and pasting it.

is there a way to do this programmatically without 'sendkeys' ?

i do not want to look at the html source at all, i just want to copy the text on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of screen scraping for applications and have found this to be invaluable:
https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader

There is a bit of sample code on that page but I've added a bit extra here that will return exactly what you want

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Function FromHtml(ByVal reader As TextReader) As XmlDocument
    '' setup SgmlReader   
    Dim sgmlReader As Sgml.SgmlReader = New Sgml.SgmlReader()
    sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML"
    sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
    sgmlReader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower
    sgmlReader.InputStream = reader
    '' create document 
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = True
    doc.XmlResolver = Nothing
    doc.Load(sgmlReader)
    Return doc
End Function

Function LoadWebText(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim objWebClient As New WebClient()
    Dim objUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()

    Dim xml As New XmlDocument
    xml = FromHtml(New StringReader(objUTF8.GetString(objWebClient.DownloadData(URL))))

    Return xml.InnerText()

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to load yahoo.com through Microsoft's Internet controls and print the text.

Create a new project in Visual Studio, go to the Add Reference page, click the COM tab and add Microsoft Internet Controls.

Then paste the code below in a function.

```
Dim MyBrowser As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

MyBrowser.Navigate("http://www.yahoo.com/")

Do Until MyBrowser.Busy = False

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

Loop

Debug.Print(MyBrowser.Document.body.innerText)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to be able to quickly copy all the content to the clipboard, you can use a bookmark that runs javascript (bookmarklet), instead of creating a bookmark with a url you would include the following:

```
javascript:void function(){document.addEventListener("copyText",function(t){t.preventDefault(),t.clipboardData%26%26t.clipboardData.setData("text/plain",document.body.innerText)}),document.execCommand("copyText")}();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check this out.

http://www.searcharoo.net/